# How to disable 3.3 Tooltips?

Tags: wp-admin, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I find the 3.3 Tooltips annoying when I'm upgrading many live and dev sites. How do I disable them via functions.php? Unenqueue wp-includes/js/wp-pointer.js ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also remove the pointer script and style from their respective arrays just after they have been registered using this method.

```
// Remove javascript
add_action( 'wp_default_scripts' , 'remove_pointer_script' );
function remove_pointer_script( $wp_scripts ) {
    $wp_scripts->remove('wp-pointer');
}

// Remove stylesheet
add_action( 'wp_default_styles' , 'remove_pointer_style' );
function remove_pointer_style( $wp_styles ) {
    $wp_styles->remove('wp-pointer');
}
```

The `remove` method is part of the [dependencies class](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-includes/class.wp-dependencies.php) which is extended by both the `WP_Scripts` and `WP_Styles` classes, it basically does the inverse of the `add` method, which is used inside core to register default scripts and styles. Mentioned incase you're curious where that method comes from and what it's for..

I suppose you could also encapsulate those actions in a `current_user_can` check also if you wanted to wipe them out for specific users, say admins.

```
if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    add_action( 'wp_default_scripts' , 'remove_pointer_script' );
    add_action( 'wp_default_styles' , 'remove_pointer_style' );
}
```

Personally i quite like the new tooltips, and it's quite a shame there's not a simple API available for utilizing them in plugins *yet*, but i can see how it could be annoying when you're doing numerous installs or upgrades and just need to get things done.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Interesting about the dependencies class; didn't know that. These things get more interesting the farther I get into them. I plan on leaving the tooltips in for beginning users, but I want to add the remove functions to several basic dev theme frameworks I use, at least for me, usually ID #1 user.

Comment: Happy to help as always.. :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, just dequeue the script (and the styles):

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'no_pointers');

function no_pointers(){
  wp_dequeue_script('wp-pointer');
  wp_dequeue_style('wp-pointer');
}
```

Or you can just disable them **permanently** for a specific user (only run once):

```
WP_Internal_Pointers::dismiss_pointers_for_new_users($user_id = 0);
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to give the answer to t31os for a more complete answer. But the php function to write to the database is helpful and I will look into that more.